# Not getting the current GPS values

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am Doing a small app which requires the current GPS values. For this i read many tutorials and i tried using this [sample code](http://androidcompetencycenter.com/wp-content/uploads/GPSApp.zip). but i am not getting the values. when i run the code it forcibly closing the application. Here is my logcat.

```
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: onCreate
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate(Native Method)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at com.android.and.AndActivity.onCreate(AndActivity.java:48)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-27 12:57:49.881: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT**

Here is my Activity.

```
public class AndActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
            int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
            latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
            longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
        } else {
            latituteField.setText("Provider not available");
            longitudeField.setText("Provider not available");
        }
    }

    /* Request updates at startup */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your AndActivity `onCreate(..)` code and xml layout you use for this Activity.

Comment: @ a.ch i added my AndActivity here..

Comment: Which line is 48th in your Activity?

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Do you really have this code: `AndActivity extends Activity`, not this: `AndActivity extends MapActivity`? I cannot imagine why MapActivity is getting called in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i got the code working in my phone. the code is not working in my emulator. When i install this on a phone it works fine.
Thank you for responses.

Answer (score 1):

Some useful links for get own current GPS coordinates.

http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/

http://www.oudmaijer.com/2010/04/15/android-retrieving-your-current-location/

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/find-current-location-in-android-gps.html

http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslocationmaps/209-obtaining-user-location

http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslocationmaps/226-android-location-providers-gps-network-p

You can find more easy and clear information about get user's current GPS coordinates. Some of the tutorials are also there. Hope this will help you.

**EDIT**

Try this...

```
public class gpsactivity {

    private static final int gpsMinTime = 6000;
    private static final int gpsMinDistance = 1;

    private LocationManager locationManager = null;
    private LocationListener locationListener = null;
    private Location location;
    private String bestProvider;
    private GPSCallback gpsCallback = null;
    private GeomagneticField geoField;

    public gpsactivity() {
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onProviderDisabled(final String provider) {
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(final String provider) {
            }

            public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
                if (location != null && gpsCallback != null) {
//                  gpsCallback.onGPSUpdate(location);

                    geoField = new GeomagneticField(
                             Double.valueOf(location.getLatitude()).floatValue(),
                             Double.valueOf(location.getLongitude()).floatValue(),
                             Double.valueOf(location.getAltitude()).floatValue(),
                             System.currentTimeMillis()
                          );
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };
    }

    public Location getCurrentLocation() {

        if (locationManager != null && bestProvider != null
                && bestProvider.length() > 0) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        }
        return location;
    }
```

And call this class by

```
 gpsManager = new gpsactivity();            
    location = gpsManager.getCurrentLocation();

    if (gpsManager != null) 
            {
                Longitude = location.getLongitude();
                Latitude = location.getLatitude();


                if (location != null) 
                {
                    location.setLatitude(Latitude);
                    location.setLongitude(Longitude);           
                }
            }

            intLatitude = (int) (Latitude * 1000000);
            intLongitude = (int) (Longitude * 1000000);
```

Thanks...

Comment: Thak you, I already tried no of codes, but not getting the output. am getting o/p only when i send the values from the emulator control.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
remove implements LocationListener from 
public class AndActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener

and create separate class like
 public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

and implement the override functions in this class.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Volworin said right..

emulator we are not get the Curent GPS location.. You must and should install your application in phone..

by the by you first ON the GPS status in phone.

follow this link.. [click link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-location-based-services.html)

I already tried it and test it in android mobile phone.. Its working.

have a nice day.